# How to Handle the Child Window in the Selenium Web Driver TestNg by Using Frame Work?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In this code i am using the Single class and the Functional Class, Here AllpagesLogins it is a Class Name and the this Code is Writing in the Functional Class, Overall Scripit is running in the TestNg Class. So when i click on the linkBtn Name as matrimonials@shaadi.com
it is displaying the Child Window in that Child Window Close Link Button Is There, So i am write the Code for the Child Window Code also and by Direct Code, But no one is not Working Correctly? How can i handle this Child Window?

```
package EmailMessage;

import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Assert;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import Class.AllpagesLogins;

//Declaring the Class Name

public class EmailMessage 
{

public void EMSG(WebDriver driver) throws Exception
{

//Here AllpagesLogins is a Class Name

AllpagesLogins APL = new AllpagesLogins();

//Clicking on the Email Message Menu Button

driver.findElement(By.id(APL.EMSG_EmailMsg_MenuBtn_ID)).click();

System.out.println("Clicked on the Email Message Menu Button");

Thread.sleep(2000);

//Checking the Text for the Email Message Title

WebElement asserta=driver.findElement(By.id(APL.EMSG_EmailMsg_MainTitle_ID));

String a=asserta.getText();

try

 {

Assert.assertEquals("Email Messages", a);

System.out.println("Main Title Name as Email Messages");

 }

catch (Error e1)

{


 System.out.println("Wrong Title");

}  

//Checking the Text for the Sub Label

WebElement assertb=driver.findElement(By.id(APL.EMSG_EmailMsg_SubLbl_ID));

String b=assertb.getText();

 try

{

Assert.assertEquals("Click on the Sender Email to view its details.", b);

System.out.println("Main Title Name as Sub Label");

}

catch (Error e1)

{

System.out.println("Wrong Title");

}

//Clicking on the Child Window

//getting parent Id

String Currenthandle=driver.getWindowHandle();

System.out.println("parent window id:"+Currenthandle);

//handle the child window

Set<String> handles= driver.getWindowHandles();

handles.remove(Currenthandle);

//performing action on child window

driver.switchTo().window(handles.iterator().next());

Thread.sleep(3000);


//Clicking on the Email Message Menu Button
            if(driver.findElement(By.linkText("matrimonials@shaadi.com")).isDisplayed())

{

System.out.println("Link Name is Displaying");

driver.findElement(By.linkText("matrimonials@shaadi.com")).click();

System.out.println("Clicked on the Email Id Link Button");

Thread.sleep(2000);

}

else

{

System.out.println("Link Name is Not Displaying");

}


//Handing the Child Windows 

if(driver.findElement(By.name("Message Details")).isDisplayed())

{

System.out.println("Message Details Label is Displaying");
                driver.findElement(By.id(APL.EMSG_ChildWindow_Close_LnkBtn_ID)).click();

System.out.println("Clicked on the Close Button in the Child Window");

Thread.sleep(2000);

}

else


{

System.out.println("Message Details Label is Not Displaying");

}


}

}
```

Comment: I don't understand sorry.  Are you talking about a popup window?

Comment: i am taking about Child Window.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver childDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfChildWindow");
childDriver.close();

Answer (score 0):

```
//after clicking button . switch to the window using this code

Set<String> winids = driver.getWindowHandles();
String mainWindow = winids.iterator().next();
String childWindow = winids.iterator().next();
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);//this switches to the child window 

//after switching perform the operations which u want to perform on the child window
```