# Selenium webdriver Java handle more than 2 child window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a web based application that launches a child window for every operation that I do in that particular new window. Eg: Parent window(parentButton)->Child1 window(child1Button)->Child2 window(child2Button)

I click a Pbutton in Parent window will launch Child window-1. I click Cbutton1 in Child window-1 will launch Child Window-2. I click Cbutton2 in Child window-2 and it will launch Child Window-3.

So, I assumed that I have launch the browser application and I have to switch to Child Window-1, perform the cbutton-1, switch to Child window-2, perform cbutton-2 operation, switch to child window-3 and send some text in this window's text area.

Here's is my code in Java,

```
    /* driver launches and logs in to the Parent window */
    String winHandleConsole = driver.getWindowHandle();
    log.info("Title of Console window: " +driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(Constants.lnkIncidentManagement).click();
    Set<String> strHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    log.info("Size of window handle: "+strHandles.size());
    for(String handle: strHandles){
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        String strTitle = driver.getTitle();
        if(strTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Incident Management Console(Search)")){
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOutInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.findElement(Constants.lnkNewIncident).click();
                Set<String> strHandle_2 = driver.getWindowHandles();
                log.info("NEW WINDOW HANDLES: "+ strHandle_2.size());
                for(String handle_2: strHandle_2){
                    log.info("-------:" + driver.getTitle());
                    if(driver2.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Incident (New)")){
                        log.info("Title of Incident-New: "+ driver2.getTitle());
                        driver.switchTo().window(handle_2);
                        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOutInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        driver.findElement(Constants.txtNewIncidentSummary).sendKeys("This is a text");

                    }
                }
            }`
```

I see a new window with the title 'Incidents (New)' and when I print the size of strHandle_2, I see 3 prited. However when I print the handle_2 variable, I don't see the Title printed.

What should I do to switch from parent to child1 and from child1 to child2?

Comment: Can you post the html you are dealing with?

Comment: @LittlePanda, the html is not needed for this question. My exact question is mentioned clearly in the last line of my original post. Moreover, the html is too big to attach.

Comment: I found a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379410/how-to-handle-the-child-window-in-the-selenium-web-driver-testng-by-using-frame

Comment: If you know the window name use `switchTo().window("name")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
package selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class BookToCart 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        //Instantiating FirefoxDriver
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Maximize the browser
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Implicit wait for 10 seconds
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //To launch softwaretestingmaterial.com
        driver.get("http://wikipedia.com");

        WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.id("js-link-box-es"));
        Actions newwin = new Actions(driver);                newwin.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(link).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        WebElement link2 = driver.findElement(By.id("js-link-box-it"));
        Actions newwin2 = new Actions(driver);
        newwin.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(link2).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        WebElement link3 = driver.findElement(By.id("js-link-box-en"));
        Actions newwin3 = new Actions(driver);              
        newwin.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(link3).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        int count=0;

        String win = driver.getWindowHandle();

        ArrayList<String> allWindows = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());


        driver.switchTo().window(allWindows.get(1));
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        WebElement about = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Find out about Wikipedia']"));
        about.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you are already working with two windows and now you want to click a link which will open third window and you want to switch on third window:
I have written a simple logic and its working................
Pass the WebElement where you want to click..............

```
public static void switchToWindow(WebElement ele)
    {
        try {
            Set<String> OldAllWindows = GenericMethods.driver.getWindowHandles();
            ele.click();
            Set<String> NewAllWindows = GenericMethods.driver.getWindowHandles();
            for(String newWindow : NewAllWindows)
            {
                if(!OldAllWindows.contains(newWindow))
                {
                    GenericMethods.driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
                }
            }

            //  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Issue in Switching Window"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `GenericMethods`